# Understanding the behavior of a smoothed notion of perimeter for general measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

**The Question:**

Let $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth function with compact support satisfying $\int f =0$, and define $f_r(x) = r^{-1} f(x/r)$.  One can show that, when $E\subset [0,1]$ is a measurable set with finite perimeter, that 
$$
P(E) = C \lim_{r\to 0^+} r^{-1}\|f_r\ast 1_E\|_{L^2}^2
$$
where the constant $C$ depends on the function $f$.  Here $1_E$ is the indicator function of $E$.

To get intuition about this formula, observe that the convolution is zero deep in the interior or exterior of $E$, and only nonzero in a strip of width approximately $r$ on the boundary of $E$.  Thus the norm captures how much mass is near the boundary, in a smoothed way.

My question is what happens when $E$ does not necessarily have finite perimeter.

> Is it true that $\lim_{r\to 0^+}r^{-1}\|f_r\ast 1_E\|_{L^2}^2 = \infty$ when $P(E) = \infty$?

It turns out to be tricky, since we do not have a nice structure theorem for such sets, and in particular there does not have to exist a scale $r$ at which the behavior of the convolution "settles" into something understandable.

**A Reduction**

If $E\subset [0,1]$ has infinite perimeter, one can find disjoint intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_N$ in $[0,1]$ such that $0 < |I_k\cap E| < |I_k|$ for all $k$.  Throwing away at most half, we can assume that the intervals are separated (none share endpoints).  Since we can do this for any $N$ and using a simple rescaling argument, it suffices to prove the following statement:

> Does there exist a constant $c>0$ such that the following holds:
>
> For any measurable set $E\subset [0,1]$ with $0<|E|<1$, 
>   $$
> \lim_{r\to 0^+} r^{-1}\|f_r\ast E\|_{L^2}^2 > c?$$

If we want we can even assume above that $P(E) = \infty$, though I'm not sure whether that helps.  Notice that this is easy to prove when $E$ is also assumed to have finite perimeter, oddly the infinite perimeter case is what is difficult!

**A Potentially useful formula**

Expanding the convolution and the square, using the fact that $\int f = 0$, and applying a change of coordinates, one can show that 
$$
r^{-1}\|f_r\ast 1_E\|_{L^2}^2 = -\frac{1}{2r}\int |E\Delta (E+rt)| g(t)\,dt
$$
where 
$$
g(t) = \int f(y) f(y+t)\,dy.
$$
From the definition one has that $\max |g| = |g(0)| = \|f\|_{L^2}^2$, and 
$\int g = 0$.  I can expand on the derivation of this formula if desired, though it is worth noting that the manipulations are largely the same as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302545/why-is-int-int-fxfy-x-ydxdy-negative) I asked a few years ago which was motivated by the same problem.

It is also possible to express this formula using the Fourier transform, but I haven't been able to get anything from this approach that is not already contained above.  Perhaps however if I had a different way to understand $\widehat{1_E}(\xi)$ I could make more progress.

**Final Thoughts**

While I am writing this I realize that perhaps this question is more appropriate for MathOverflow as it is a question that came up in research and I'm not sure that it has a known answer.  Please let me know if this is the case.  In the meantime I'd be very happy to see either a counterexample or any other angle of attack.

Thank you very much.